# Copied a package to site-packages, but pip doesn't list it. How can I make pip aware of the installed package?

Tags: python, pip

I had to manually build a package and copy it to the site-packages directory. When I type `pip list` into a console it isn't listed, though I can use it in python scripts. How can I make pip aware of the package?

Installing it via pip is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "Installing it via pip is not an option.", but I'm assuming installing it via pip using a local copy still is. If so, the way to do that is to clone your library into a directory (say `/my/lib/dir`), where the root of the source for the root package appears below `/my/lib/dir` (ex: if the package you want to install is imported as `import foo`, then you should have `/my/lib/dir/foo`). If there is no file named `setup.py` in your copy of the code, then you need to create a simple one. Something like

```
# in a file called setup.py above the `foo` directory
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      packages=['foo'],
 )
```

Finally, run `pip install .` from `/my/lib/dir`.

It's definitely a hack, but making pip aware of a package without installing it via pip is asking for a hack :-)

Comment: Perfect! Note that pip will use the directory the folder is in as the install location, so if you want it in site-packages you'll need to install it from there.

Comment: If you need it in `site-packages`, omit the `-e` switch: `pip install .`. The `-e` switch is for editable installs serving the development purposes.